# The api usage measured by mql in gcp cloud monitoring is different from the actual value viewed on the quota page

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota, google-play-developer-api, google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

I'm trying to get a notification when Google api quota usage exceeds a certain percentage. Below is the mql I wrote and counted on a 1 day basis and summed it on a service basis. Calculate the number of quotas used/allocated and try to get notification when it is higher then 0.5.

```html
fetch consumer_quota
| { metric 'serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/rate/net_usage'
| filter (resource.service == 'androidpublisher.googleapis.com')
| group_by 1d, [value_net_usage_aggregate: aggregate(value.net_usage)]
| every 1d
| group_by [resource.service],
[value_net_usage_aggregate_aggregate:
aggregate(value_net_usage_aggregate)] }
| div( 200000 )
| mul(100)
| condition val() > .5
```

The problem is that **these measured values do not match the numbers viewed on the quota page**.

[image]

The problem seems to be that the **criteria for calculating time are different.**

- Monitoring time standard : UTC + 9
- Quota page time standard : UTC - 8
  (Daily quotas reset at midnight Pacific Time)

How can I change the mql to day time standard?

Answer (score 2):

For calculating daily quota using custom time zone in MQL, what you need is [timestamp_to_string](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference?hl=en#timestamp_to_string-func) and [the list of time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

The MQL based alert might be like:

```
fetch consumer_quota
| metric 'serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/rate/net_usage' 
| filter (resource.service == 'androidpublisher.googleapis.com')
| map add [yyyymmdd: end().timestamp_to_string("%Y%m%d", "America/Los_Angeles").string_to_int64] 
| group_by [yyyymmdd], sliding(24h), [s: sum(val(0))]
| every 30s
| align mean_aligner(30s)
| value val() / 200000
| condition val() > 0.5
```

Note that we are grouping by the `yyyymmdd` here so it will create different alerts for different dates.